# Is it possible in Linux to have the two connections from the same client port to different server ports?

Tags: linux, networking, language-agnostic, client-server, tcp

Say, the IP address of my Linux system is 10.0.0.2.

Is it possible, under any imaginable circumstance, that there are two connections that may look like the following, i.e. two connections with the same client port (e.g. `10.0.0.2:21426`) connecting to two separate server ports (e.g. `10.0.0.2:5000` and `10.0.0.2:5001`)?

```
10.0.0.2:21426 --> 10.0.0.2:5000
10.0.0.2:21426 --> 10.0.0.2:5001
```

I don't care if the two client ports belong to the same process or different processes. I also don't care if the two server ports belong to the same process or different processes.

I just want to know if there is any possible situation where the above mentioned scenario is possible.

Comment: It's theoretically possible, but I don't think it will actually happen in practice. I don't think there's an API that will allow binding two connections to the same local port.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. A good example of this is FTP, where multiple file transfers in active mode would all originate from `10.0.0.2:20` to the various clients.